# Laplace transform on a continuous function on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform

Let g be a continuous function.
I would like to show that $\lim_{h\to \infty} h \int_{t=0}^1 e^{-ht}g(t)dt=g(0)$.
I try to solve it by integration by part, but that does not work. Is there any way to show it except using DCT.

Comment: How does DCT help???

Comment: Substitute $x=th$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the susbstitution $s=ht$. We have to show that $\int_0^{h}e^{-s} g(\frac s h)ds \to g(0)$. Use the following steps:

1. Let $r=\frac 1 {\sqrt h}$. By continuity of $g$ at $0$ we see that $|\int_0^{rh} e^{-s} [g(\frac s h)-g(0)]ds|<\epsilon \int_0^{\infty} e^{-s} ds/2 =\epsilon/2$ if $h$ is large enough.
2. $|\int_{rh}^{h} e^{-s} [g(\frac s h)-g(0)]ds|\leq C \int_{rh}^{h} e^{-s}ds$ where $C$ is bound for $g(\frac s h)-g(0)$. Note that $\int_{rh}^{h} e^{-s}ds=e^{-rh}-e^{-h}  <\epsilon/{2C}$ if $e^{-rh} <\epsilon/2C$.
3. Finally note that $\int_0^{h} e^{-s} g(0)ds \to g(0)$ as $ h \to \infty$.

Comment: I am a little bit confused about the first step. Because if h is large enough, s will also grow.

Comment: @wenti $s/h<r=h^{-1/2}$

Comment: I kind of get your idea.  As $h$ large enough, $r$ goes to $0$. Then $g(r)-g(0) < $. But I still cannot understand why s/h <r.

Comment: Is that because the integration is from 0 to rh?

Comment: Yes, we are integrating over the range $0<s<rh$ @wenti